# another way to connect with ZEND auth ldap

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication, ldap

I want to connect to a ldap server. I've done it by using the following code in application.ini

```
ldap.server.host = ldaps://ldap.example.ro
ldap.server.username = "uid=admin,ou=people,dc=example,dc=ro"
ldap.server.password = "password"
ldap.server.baseDn = "ou=people,dc=example,dc=ro"
ldap.server.bindRequiresDn = true
```

and then

```
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    $config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini',
                                'production');
    $options = $config->ldap->toArray();

    $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_Ldap($options, $username, $password);

    $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
```

Is there any way that i can do the same thing just without admin and password ?
without ldap.server.username and ldap.server.password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way. So simple...

in application.ini

```
 ldap.server.host = ldaps://ldap.example.ro
 ldap.server.baseDn = "ou=people,dc=example,dc=ro"
```

and the only difference is that the $username must be

```
 $username = "uid=". $username . ",ou=people,dc=example,dc=ro"
```